# Wondering if a situation might warrant this?

Tags: swift

I fond this bit of code:

```
func generate(withParams params: [String : AnyObject], andWord word: String?) -> String {

    guard
        let params = params as [String : AnyObject]?,
        let word = word as String?
        else { fatalError() }
return "stuff"
}
```

Guarding against word being nil makes sense to me, but I see no use for the params cast to something more permissive.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing anything – `guard let params = params as [String : AnyObject]?` is thoroughly pointless (and casting `word` to `String?` is unnecessary).

Comment: And honestly, using unwrapping an optional to only just `fatalError()`, giving no info, is no better than just force unwrapping (`!`). It's even stupider that this function takes `word` as a `String?` in the first place.

Comment: I really do hope this is just a simplified example, and the real code doesn't just `fatalError()` for a `nil` `word` input, and otherwise return `"stuff"`.

Comment: @Hamish it is somewhat simplified ;)